Invalid mime type "zip": does not contain '/'
Here is the docs link for downloading artifact from Github Workflow
I have following code:
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        String token = "token";
        String artifactUrl = "https://api.github.com/repos/OWNER/REPO/actions/artifacts/ARTIFACT_ID/zip";
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Accept", "application/vnd.github+json");
        headers.setBearerAuth(token);
        headers.set("X-GitHub-Api-Version", "2022-11-28");

        // Create a HttpEntity with the HttpHeaders
        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(headers);

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = restTemplate.exchange(artifactUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, byte[].class);

        // Save the response body (artifact content) to a file
        Path outputPath = Paths.get("artifact.zip");
        Files.write(outputPath, response.getBody());
    }
}

when i run above code, i am getting this below error:
Caused by: org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "zip": does not contain '/'
I have token with right permission to download artifact: repo, workflow
